# Qt3DWindow performance issue on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: c++, performance, qt, ubuntu, qt3d

My problem is that I want to create a `Qt3DWindow` which I embed in my program using `QWidget::createWindowContainer`.

I now upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10 but as soon as I add the container widget my CPU load goes up to 100% constant.

**This worked already under Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows.**

Does anyone know this issue or maybe even have a solution? Or do I have to downgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 again?

A minimally working example is creating a new project in Qt Creator and selecting Qt Widgets Application and, finally, replacing the code in the `mainwindow.cpp` with the following:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <Qt3DExtras/Qt3DWindow>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
   QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->centralWidget->setLayout(new QHBoxLayout());
    Qt3DExtras::Qt3DWindow *window = new Qt3DExtras::Qt3DWindow;
    QWidget *widget = QWidget::createWindowContainer(window);
    ui->centralWidget->layout()->addWidget(widget);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Now add `3dextras` to `QT += core gui` in the .pro file of your project and run it. This produces the high CPU load on my machine.